# Xul tree, editable attribute

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have a xul tree already created and I'd like to make it no editable.
For that, via javascript, I put:

```
document.getElementById("myTree").setAttribute("editable", "false");
```

But it doesn't have any effects.
I'd like the tree doesn't accept drag and drop, context menu, and keyboard shortcuts on the tree elements. Does the editable attribute have effects on that ?

Comment: Have you tried setting `editable` attribute directly?
`document.getElementById("myTree").editable = "false";`